# Expected behavior using grunt's file array format and templates?

Tags: gruntjs

Question for any GruntJS gurus out there...

Background: In my quest to better understand templates in grunt's initConfig method I have been toying around with them a bit. I quickly <strike>progressed</strike> stumbled to a point where either I am doing it wrong (the most likely reason) or it is not supported. So this isn't a question about *why* I am doing this but **how** to do it.

My question is this: using the [files array format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format) for specifying a `files` option for a task, is it possible to have one sub task for one set of files, another task for another set of files and then a third task that simply references the first two subtasks' `files` options combined using a template?

For example using the `copy` task:

```
copy: {
    build_web: {
        files: [
            {
                // robots.txt, favicon.ico, etc
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.web.src.dir %>',
                dest: '<%= config.web.build.dir %>',
                src: [ '*.{ico,txt}' ]
            },
            {
                // App JavaScript files
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.web.src.dir %>',
                dest: '<%= config.web.build.dir %>scripts/',
                src: [ 'scripts/**/*.js' ]
            },
            {
                // App minified 3rd party JavaScript files
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.web.src.dir %>',
                dest: '<%= config.web.build.dir %>scripts/components/',
                src: [ 'components/**/*.min.js' ]
            },
        ]
    },
    build_server: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.server.src.dir %>',
                dest: '<%= config.server.build.dir %>',
                src: [ '**/*' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    build_all: {
        // This works
        files: '<%= copy.build_web.files %>'
        // So does this
        files: '<%= copy.build_server.files %>'
        // But this doesn't work (interpolation)
        files: '<%= copy.build_web.files.concat( copy.build_server.files ) %>'
    }
}
```

<sup>** Obviously only one `files` option is used at a time for the `copy:build_all` task but I have included all three for brevity. (/me laughs)*</sup>

Since the `files` option expects an array as a possible input, the first two work without an issue. So, shouldn't concat'ing them together to return a new array work?

**UPDATE:** Checking the output using verbose logging `-v`, shows there are no files matched using the concat, `Files: [no files]`, but I can't tell what the task is using for the pattern matching.

Testing the templates directly shows the concat is working...

```
grunt.log.writeln( grunt.template.process( '<%= copy.build_web.files[0].src %>' ) );
=> *.{ico,txt}
grunt.log.writeln( grunt.template.process( '<%= copy.build_web.files.concat( copy.build_server.files )[0].src %>' ) );
=> *.{ico,txt}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the GruntJS source files I believe I found the reason on [line 49 of the config.js file](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/config.js#L49):

```
// Match '<%= FOO %>' where FOO is a propString, eg. foo or foo.bar but not
// a method call like foo() or foo.bar().
```

I am not sure if the [Template docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates) should mention this since it might be covered somewhere else, but maybe at least reference it?